# Imported PostGIS layer has no geometry

Tags: qgis, postgis, geojson

I have a PostGis table I have generated by importing an existing geojson file using ogr2ogr. When I add this table as a layer in QGIS, the layer shows up as having no geometry. In the layer properties I get:

> **Geometry type of the features in this layer**
>
> No geometry (WKB type: "NoGeometry")

The table has geometry data in the wkb_geometry column with binary data, and if I export the table using ogr2ogr I get the correct geojson object reconstructed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "with binary data" can you output the table definition \d?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this or what you are expecting. But the wkb_geometry is of bytea type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostGis installed, but database not configured for PostGis...

So for future reference, run this:

> CREATE EXTENSION postgis